# Labels as a matrix in LMDB data using python

Tags: python, pycaffe, lmdb

I want to create a lmdb data in python where the labels are not scalars but each label is (1,K) vector and K is the number of classes. More specifically, the label vector has zeros everywhere except in the corresponding class index you have 1.

I tested the following code in python:

```
with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
    for i in range(N):
        datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
        datum.channels = X.shape[1]
        datum.height = X.shape[2]
        datum.width = X.shape[3]
        datum.data = X[i].tobytes()  # or .tostring() if numpy < 1.9
        datum.label = int(y[i])
        str_id = '{:08}'.format(i)
        txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), datum.SerializeToString())
        print i+1
```

But I got the this error `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` where `y[i]` is a numpy (1,k) vector as described above.

I am also wondering if caffe would accept such format of labels.

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, caffe supports transformation of numpy arrays to datum, then you can put the datum to lmdb.

Using `caffe.io.array_to_datum(numpy_array)` to transform a numpy_array to datum, NOTE that the numpy_array must have 4 axes, so if you want to put a vecttor into lmdb, you should initialize a numpy_array with shape [1,1,1,M], while M is the length of your vector.

[here](https://github.com/zeakey/tools/blob/master/img-img2lmdb.py) is a tool to write image/map pairs to lmdb which can be feed to caffe networks.